How can i deep Linking with my mobile application in Xamarin Forms
I want to linking web site url to my mobile application.
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              DataScheme = "https",
              DataHost = "polis.ateshgah.com",
              DataPathPrefix = "/",
              AutoVerify = true,
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              DataScheme = "http",
              DataHost = "polis.ateshgah.com",
              DataPathPrefix = "/",
              AutoVerify = true,
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

I added this attribute to MainActivity.
I am using Xamarin.Form.AppLinks Nuget Packageand adding AndroidAppLinks.Init(this); in OnCreate() method.
I was configure my website.
But it is not working. My application is not suggest or openend when go to my website.

Have you followed this document: App-Linking in Android?

@JessieZhang-MSFT yes i did. i didnt get error. But i dont know why is not working? I cant see any behaviour on browser when go to my website

Is there any log about this problem?

@JessieZhang-MSFT srry there is no any error. Just not working. I check my output i cant see any log about deeplink

Could you please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example here so that we can help you better?
